# HBase FuzzyRowFilter doesn't work

Tags: filter, hbase

I have a row key composed of twenty characters like this:

> XXAAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I want to scan using a `FuzzyRowFilter` on the AA value on 2 to 6 position . But `AA` is not fixed value.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have AAAA as fixed,you can do like this :

```
FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);
String[] matches=new String[]{"AAAA","BBBB"};
    for (String match:matches) {
        byte[] rk = Bytes.toBytesBinary("??" + match + "??????????????");
        byte[] fuzzyVal = new byte[]{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        List<Pair<byte[], byte[]>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        pairs.add(new Pair<>(rk, fuzzyVal));
        filterList.addFilter(new FuzzyRowFilter(pairs));
    }
Scan scan=new Scan();
    scan.setFilter(filterList);
```

This will filter based on all the fuzzyFilters in the list and match based on FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE.
Based on your requirements,go ahead and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but using,

```
FilterList filterList = new FilterList(/*FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE*/);
    String[] matches=new String[]{"1609","1610"};
        for (String match:matches) {
            byte[] rk = Bytes.toBytesBinary("??" + match + "??????????????");
            byte[] fuzzyVal = new byte[]{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
            List<Pair<byte[], byte[]>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
            pairs.add(new Pair<>(rk, fuzzyVal));
            filterList.addFilter(new FuzzyRowFilter(pairs));
        }
    Scan scan_fuzzy=new Scan();
    scan_fuzzy.setFilter(filterList);

    ResultScanner rs_fuzzy = table.getScanner(scan);

    for( Result result : rs_fuzzy) {
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("Value: "  + Bytes.toString(result.getValue(FAMILY,COLUMN)));
    }
```

my result doesn't contain just the row corresponding to the rowkey :02160901222720647002

but all the row (and the rowkey) of my table